# TypeScript: How to infer Array item type using Mapped Types

Tags: typescript, types

I have a question, how to get the array item type via mapped types
For example here when I use `array` method I can infer the type of array item, but how to made it in `arrayStr` method? And why in this example aStrId has type 'never'?

[Sandbox](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20One%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20data%3A%20T%0D%0A%20%20%20%20)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20array%3CR%3E(getter%3A%20((obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20R%5B%5D))%3A%20Two%3CR%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20arrayStr%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20T%2C%20R%3E(name%3A%20K%2C%20idField%3A%20keyof%20R)%3A%20Two%3CR%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Two%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getItem()%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20getAsArray()%3A%20T%5B%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20%5B%7B%20q%3A%201%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20q%3A%202%20%7D%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20one%20%3D%20new%20One(data)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20one.array(p%20%3D%3E%20p.a)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20aValue%20%3D%20a.getItem().q%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20oneStr%20%3D%20new%20One(data)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20aStre%20%3D%20oneStr.arrayStr('a')%3B%0D%0Aconst%20aStrValue%20%3D%20aStre.getItem().q%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20oneStrId%20%3D%20new%20One(data)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20aStrId%20%3D%20oneStrId.arrayStr('a'%2C%20'q')%3B%0D%0Aconst%20aStrValueId%20%3D%20aStre.getItem().q%3B)

```
class One<T> {

    constructor(
        data: T
    ) { }

    array<R>(getter: ((obj: T) => R[])): Two<R> {
        return null;
    }

    arrayStr<K extends keyof T, R>(name: K, idField: keyof R): Two<R> {
        return null;
    }

}

class Two<T> {

    getItem(): T {
        return null;
    }

    getAsArray(): T[] {
        return [];
    }

}

const data = {
    a: [{ q: 1 }, { q: 2 }]
};

const one = new One(data);
const a = one.array(p => p.a);
const aValue = a.getItem().q;

const oneStr = new One(data);
const aStre = oneStr.arrayStr('a');
const aStrValue = aStre.getItem().q;

const oneStrId = new One(data);
const aStrId = oneStrId.arrayStr('a', 'q');
const aStrValueId = aStre.getItem().q;
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding the question.  Can you post the code directly along with specific places you're having problems?  What is the `arrayStr()` method supposed to do?  The signature is strange (there doesn't seem to be any way to know what `R` is supposed to be) and the implementation (`return null`) doesn't give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I have got an answer here at TypeScript Gitter [link](https://gitter.im/Microsoft/TypeScript?at=59c2ef077b7d98d30d1c83a0).
This will work:

```
arrayStr<K extends keyof T, R, E>(this: One<{[k in K]: R[] | E}>, name: K): Two<R> {
```